# Cancel HttpClient request on connection lost

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, httpclient

I have the following method, on a windows-store project, to upload a file

```
public async Task<Boolean> UploadFileStreamService(Stream binaries, String fileName, String filePath)
    {

        try
        {
            filePath = Uri.EscapeDataString(filePath);

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = Constants.baseAddress })
            {

                var content = new StreamContent(binaries);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", App.Current.Resources["token"] as string);
                App.Current.Resources["TaskUpload"] = true;
                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("file?fileName=" + filePath, content))
                {

                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (responseData.Contains("errorCode"))
                        throw new Exception("Exception: " + responseData);

                    else
                    {
                        JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject();
                        JsonObject.TryParse(responseData, out jObj);
                        if (jObj.ContainsKey("fileId"))
                        {
                            if (jObj["fileId"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                            {
                                App.Current.Resources["NewVersionDoc"] = jObj["fileId"].GetString();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

And on the app.xaml.cs i have on the constructor:

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged +=
        NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged; // Listen to connectivity changes
```

And on that method i check for the connection changes.

What i would like to know is how to stop a upload task when i detect that network change ( from having internet to not having).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cancellation tokens. You need `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Then pass token to your `UploadFileStreamService` method (use `_cts.Token` to get token):

```
public async Task<Boolean> UploadFileStreamService(Stream binaries, String fileName, String filePath, CancellationToken ct)
```

And use another overload of `PostAsync` which accepts token (note - also use overloads that accept tokens for all other async methods where possible, for example for `ReadAsStringAsync`):

```
using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("file?fileName=" + filePath, content, ct))
```

Then when you found network connection is lost, cancel with:

```
_cts.Cancel();
```

Note that this will throw `OperationCancelledException` on PostAsync call, which you may (or may not) want to handle somehow.

Comment: Just a followup question, if i use the same token on several PostAsync, when i do _cts.Cancel(); does it cancel all tasks with that token ?

Comment: Yes (if you use tokens from the same CancellationTokeSource - they are not necessary the same). So if you want to cancel each post separately - use different CancellationTokenSources.